# How to delete a folder from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, directory, delete

I would like to delete a folder in the Ubuntu One menu. I deleted the folder in my computer, but the folder still appears in the tab folders Ubuntu One.

How to remove the folder completely?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your folders through the Ubuntu One Website (http://one.ubuntu.com).

After you login, access the Files Tab. Click the "More" link on the folder you wish to delete in order to view the options. The "Delete Folder" option will then be visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete anything from your Ubuntu One account, then you need to delete that from your panel at Ubuntu One website (http://one.ubuntu.com).

### To delete a file/folder from Ubuntu One web panel

1. Login to your panel
2. Click on the files tab (You'll find your files/folders here)
3. Click on the **More** button at the right side of the folder name
4. Now you'll see some more options along with a **Delete** option.
5. Click on this **Delete** button to permanently delete that file/folder.